# Unexpected output while reading contents of file

Tags: java

I am facing some problem while reading the contents of file.
Although program is reading contents, it is skipping odd line data from file.

**Example of file:**

```
Czech Republic____06092015_091108   
France____06092015_060256   
Greece____06092015_073528   
Hungary____06092015_093424  
India____06092015_120741    
Indonesia____06092015_140940    
Kazakhstan____06092015_095945   
Mexico____06092015_061522   
Turkey____06092015_100457
```

**But the output is:**

```
java.io.DataInputStream@1909752

France____06092015_060256

Hungary____06092015_093424

Indonesia____06092015_140940

Mexico____06092015_061522
```

I don't understand why it is giving output as in this format.
I have line separator in input file, can it be causing the problem?

```
public class tst {
    // Main method
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Stream to read file
        FileInputStream fin;
        int k = 0;
        try {
            // Open an input stream
            fin = new FileInputStream(
                    "C:/Users/BOT2/Desktop/MC_WIth_DATA_Files.txt");
            DataInputStream in1 = new DataInputStream(fin);
            // Read a line of text
            System.out.println(new DataInputStream(fin));

            // Close our input stream
            BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1));

            while (br1.readLine() != null) {// System.out.println(k);k++;
                System.out.println(br1.readLine());
            }
            br1.close();
            fin.close();
        }
        // Catches any error conditions
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to read from file");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you are reading it twice per iteration. One in while expression and other in println method

Comment: You'd better remove all your comments. They only provide incorrect or useless information.

Answer (score 3):

The first line is printed by:

```
System.out.println( new DataInputStream(fin) );
```

it gives you te result of `new DataInputStream(fin).toString()`

The next lines are printed in this format, bacause you read two lines per loop:
first line `while (br1.readLine() != null){` and second line: `System.out.println(br1.readLine()); }`

So you have to change your code to:

```
String line;
while ((line =br1.readLine()) != null){//System.out.println(k);k++;
   System.out.println(line );
}
br1.close();
fin.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two errors. First, you print out the dataStream object for some reason. Get  rid of :

```
 // Read a line of text
 System.out.println( new DataInputStream(fin) );
```

Next, you throw away lines of text. Try this instead:

```
   String line;
   while ((line = br1.readLine()) != null){
     System.out.println(line); 
   }
```

Comment: @EvanThanks..it worked . it was cauding the prob ..shouldnt have the 2 system.out.line and should have one line read at once.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here

```
  while (br1.readLine() != null){
       System.out.println(br1.readLine()); 
      }
  br1.close();
  fin.close();        
 }
```

When you call br1.readLine() it reads out the current line and move the cursor position to point to the next line. You are calling this method twice causing you to skip alternative lines. You should call readLine() only once per iteration.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest cleaner code so you and whoever reads it will understand immediately what you are doing.

Try this :

```
Scanner read;
try{
read=new Scanner(new FileReader("your path"));


while(read.hasNext()){
System.out.println(read.nextLine);
}

read.close();
}

catch(FileNotFoundException e){
}
```